# Error while running " jekyll serve " command

Tags: jekyll

I followed the following link to install jekyll

https://davidburela.wordpress.com/2015/11/28/easily-install-jekyll-on-windows-with-3-command-prompt-entries-and-chocolatey/

However when I run " jekyll serve" , I get the following error

> jekyll 3.2.0 | Error:  different prefix: "/" and
>   "C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minima-1.0.1"

I am using os windows 10.pls help.

**Update1**:

I installed 3.1.6, but I am getting the follwoing error

```
c:\myblog>jekyll build C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:95:in block in materialize': Could not find j ekyll-3.2.0 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound) from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:inmap!' from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:88:in materialize' from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:140:inspecs' from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:185:in specs_for' from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:174:inrequested_specs' from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/environment.rb:19:in requested_specs' from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:14:insetup' from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.12.5/lib/bundler.rb:95:in setup' from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.1.6/lib/jekyll/plugin_manager.rb:33:inrequire_from_bundler' from C:/Ruby200-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/jekyll-3.1.6/bin/jekyll:9:in <top (required)>' from C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/jekyll:23:inload' from C:/Ruby200-x64/bin/jekyll:23:in `
```

**Update2:**

Updated to jekyll 3.2.1, working now. Thanks everybody.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jekyll 3.2.0 was broken on Windows. Run `gem update jekyll` to upgrade to 3.2.1 which supports Windows.

Answer (score 3):

Identical issue here.

The 3.2.0 build is currently broken for Windows. Anomaly logged on project here https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/5146 and should be fixed on a future release.

Continuing to try for a workaround. (Roll-back Jekyll version...?)

I rolled back for now :

```
gem uninstall jekyll -v 3.2.0
gem install jekyll -v 3.1.6
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out that jekyll 3.2.1 works on versions of windows 7 but does not on later versions....

Comment: I am running Jekyll 3.2.1 on Windows 10 without any problems.