# Error running Jekyll locally on Windows 10

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I created Jekyll blog on Windows 10. When I tried to run it locally using `jekyll serve` , I got these errors:

> Error reading file C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minima-1.0.1/_layouts/default.html: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minima-1.0.1/_layouts/default.html
>
> Error reading file C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minima-1.0.1/_layouts/page.html: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minima-1.0.1/_layouts/page.html
>
> Error reading file C:/tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minima-1.0.1/_layouts/post.html: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /tools/ruby23/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/minima-1.0.1/_layouts/post.html

I've searched in stackoverflow and some other sites(e.g. [Error while running " jekyll serve " command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38691001/error-while-running-jekyll-serve-command)) about this problem and found out that it will work for Jekyll version `3.2.1`. I've installed this version too and tried it out, but still failed to run locally.

I've installed all "things" needed for this like ruby, rubydevkit, python, and Jekyll. But still the only problem is I can't run it locally to test it before publishing it to GitHub pages. I only succeed publishing it to GitHub pages with no error, but not locally running. I followed the tutorials in here:

- https://martinbuberl.com/blog/setup-jekyll-on-windows-and-host-it-on-github-pages/
- https://blog.r3bl.me/en/jekyll-blogging-like-a-pro/
- http://jekyll-windows.juthilo.com/

How to run it locally?, is it not working for windows?. Thanks.

Comment: `bundle install` then `bundle exec jekyll serve`

Comment: not working, still got the same error. @DavidJacquel

Comment: If it does not work: You can run Jekyll in CloudCannon and edit in your browser. Works on all platforms.

Answer (score 0):

turn out I miss some settings and should be run with `bundle exec jekyll serve`